# Как в Mac OS IntelliJ IDEA отобразить варианты автозаполнения?

Tags: intellij-idea, hotkeys

Как в Mac OS IntelliJ IDEA отобразить варианты автозаполнения?
Меня интересуют горячие клавиши.

P.S.: в Windows это <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd>.

Comment: По умолчанию должно быть также: `Control+Shift+Space`: https://resources.jetbrains.com/assets/products/intellij-idea/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_mac.pdf

Comment: я это видел, но ничего не подходит из предложенного.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В брошюре все правильно говорится, комбинация та же, что и в Windows. Проблема была в том, что у меня в OS `ctrl+space` — это смена языка.

Для решения проблемы необходимо поменять настройки hotkey в IntelliJ IDEA на `command+space`.

Answer (score 0):

на мак М2 помогло такое
тоже при **shift+control+spase** переключался язык
я к этому комбо **добавил** зажатую кнопку **fn**(она же переключатель языка)
и сработало